# BigQuery Service Accounts config for more than one project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

While using BigQuery Java Client, need to join between Table A present in project A.dataset A and Table B present in project B.dataset B

I am able to run the query using BigQuery console and get cross-project access to the tables by specifying the complete table id i.e. project.dataset.table

Is it possible to add both projects A and B to the same service account, so that the client can be initialized with a single Google Service Account Configuration and query the tables from both the projects?

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: One can use Google IAM policy binding to achieve this. A sample command would look like gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT-ID> --role "roles/bigquery.dataViewer" --member serviceAccount:<SERVICE-ACCOUNT>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add the same Service Account to different projects.

Once you have created your Service Account in one project, copy the e-mail. Navigate to [Cloud IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) page, choosing your second project. Add the Service Account as a member with necessary BigQuery role  to your second project.